# Powerpoint changes language mid word

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, language, spell-check

PowerPoint keeps changing my language back and forth between English and Danish. And it does so in the middle of words.

An example where the **bold** is marked as misspellings:

> The **d**e**sig**n is good.

Often PowerPoint will simply highlight single letters as a different language.

What is going on?

Comment: Might you be pressing Alt+Shift accidentally? I do this once a week or so and find myself typing in Chinese.